# Grails.How to format Strings in bullet point

Tags: grails, gsp

I want the div to be dynamic.The string that i get might contain bullet point like this a :**"Uses •This is a test: •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test"**.

I have a div that shows the output:

```
                <div class="ds-results-detail-a">${a}</div>
```

How can i show that response in list like:

```
Uses 
•This is a test:
•This is a test 
•This is a test
•This is a test
•This is a test 
•This is a test
•This is a test 
•This is a test
```

The response might contain strings with those bullet point or may be simply String. The output simply shows like:

> Uses •This is a test: •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test
>   •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This is a test •This
>   is a test

How to show in list?Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right, you need to have smth like:

```
<ul>
  <g:each in="${yourString.split( '•' )}" var="s">
    <li>${s}</li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
```

UPD:

Another way:

```
${yourString.replaceAll( '•', '<br>•' )}
```

Comment: But this is printing every thing in bullet point. Even Uses is inside bullet.. i have done :"<ul>
  <g:each in="${a.split( '•' )}" var="s">
    <li>${s}</li>
  </g:each>
</ul>"  Except the word Uses other should be in list...Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry but it is printing like "Uses <br>•This is a test  <br>•This is a test  <br>•This is a test  <br>•This is a test ."

Comment: add `<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>` to the top of the page